# ajax not saving my inputs in form after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use Ajax that will keep 
the inputs that the user has entered but for some reason, it isn't working.
In case of an error, my controller redirects the view with the data of errors,
however, after the page is uploading the form is empty.
I am using the MVC model of Codeigniter.

```
$("#save").click(function () {

        var tnum1 = $("#tnum1").val();
        var tnum2 = $("#tnum2").val();
        var tnum3 = $("#tnum3").val();
        var loc = $("#loc").val();
        var dine = $("#dine").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var time = $("#time").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>" + "/hosting/create",
                data: {tnum1:tnum1, tnum2:tnum2, tnum3:tnum3, loc:loc, dine:dine, 
                date:date, time:time, phone:phone, fullname: fullname},
                error: function () {
                    alert( "Load was performed.");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "") {

                        window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('hosting/tableMap'); ?>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#error").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Controller

```
public function create() {  

            $newDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post('re_date')));
            $newTime = date("H:i", strtotime($this->input->post('re_time')));
            $data = array(
                'num' => $this->input->post('num'),
                'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                'diners' => $this->input->post('diners'),
                're_date' => $newDate,
                're_time' => $newTime,
                'phonenumber' => $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
            );

            $dataclient = array(
                'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                'phonenumber' => $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
            );

            $error = $this->validation($data,$dataclient);

        if ($error) {
              $data['error'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<b><u>Failed! </u></b>'.$error.'');
                redirect(base_url("/hosting/tableMap"));
        } else {

            $this->Hosting_model->form_insert($data, $dataclient);

            }

}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to share your controller function as well as your form to look into this matter

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the controller then it will not retain the previous values. Instead save the error in a variable and return it to ajax function.
That is the whole point of ajax - to not redirect or reload a page ie do the task asynchronously.

remove this line-

```
redirect(base_url("/hosting/tableMap")); // redirecting on error
```

then in your controller

```
if ($error) {
    // data['error'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<b><u>Failed! </u></b>'.$error.''); // remove this as page will not reload, flashdata wouldn't work
    // redirect(base_url("/hosting/tableMap"));
    $ajax_data['error'] = 1; // if error exists then value
    $ajax_data['validation_error'] = $error;
} else {
    $this->Hosting_model->form_insert($data, $dataclient);
    $ajax_data['error'] = 0;  // if error doesn't exist then value
}
return json_encode($ajax_data); // or echo json_encode($ajax_data);
```

Now, to prevent default action of form submission that is to redirect page use

```
$("#save").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
```

then in your ajax success:

```
if (data.error == 0) {  // no error
    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('hosting/tableMap'); ?>";
}
else {  // error
    $("#error").html(data); // do whatever you want to do with error
    // errors can be retrieved from "data.validation_error" -- it will be an array probably sp you'll have to loop through each element
}
```

Comment: Okay, I thought it will be a problem, it is saved is a variable. How will I return it to ajax function?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but I still have a problem because it is redirecting me to a blank page. Hopefully, I'll solve it.

Comment: that should've solved your problem, have you given any action in the form?

Comment: No I'm using:
 <?php echo form_open('Hosting/create'); ?>

Comment: yes, that's probably why. try `$("#save").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); // then rest of your code`

Comment: Okay, thank you the ajax kept the values but still it redirects me to a blank page.
I think the reason for it is that the view called tableMap and not create, so when I press submit it redirects me to hosting/create and it's only a form it's not my view page.

Comment: is your page being redirected to `Hosting/create`?

Comment: No, it isn't! That is extremely weird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213792/discussion-between-sauhardnc-and-victorias-secret).

Comment: what is the url of the redirected page?